# xUnit error messages in the Visual Studio Runner

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, xunit.net

I am using xUnit theory to group related input to the same test, such as this:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("fg00123 kj 56", "123")]
[InlineData("123", "123")]
public void NormalizeString(string input, string expectedOutput) {
    Assert.Equal(expectedOutput, MethodToTest(input));
}
```

But if the first fails I can only see the expectedOutput and actual output. I realize that I can change the expectedOutput to something unique, but it is not unreasonable to test several inputs that all give the same output. Is there no way to display in visual studios testrunner what input caused the test to fail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Assert.True which has a user message parameter:

`var actualOutput = MethodToTest(input);
Assert.True(expectedOutput==actualOutput,
            string.Format("for input {0} expected {1} but got {2}", input, expectedOutput, actualOutput));`

Comment: That works for perfectly for my usecase, and is a lot better than my hacky approach where I embedded the input string in the strings to Assert.Equal. But it's still not ideal, as it would be difficult to use with Asset.Throws for instance.

Comment: For Assert.Throws, in case you can make the tested code pass the input as a parameter to the thrown exception, than you can use the paramName argument of Assert.Throws to fail the test for the specific theory input, e.g.,
```Assert.Throws(input, throwingCode);```

Comment: I will keep that in mind if the use case arise. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Xunit.net lends itself to minimalism and self documenting code, they left the user message just on the more general assertions. See discussion over here: https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/350